# Is it good idea to have inheriting classes in one file in this example

Tags: c#

I have  2 mini classes that inherits from base class (basically model classes).

Would it be OK to create a container class with the 3 classes nested inside it in one file?

For example

```
Public class Container {
Public class animal {
} 
Public class dog:animal{
} 

Public class cat:animal {
} 
}
```

Comment: You don't need a container class - C# doesn't have an enforced "one class per file" rule like Java does (I think it does?). Whether you actually do this is a matter of opinion. You should consider the size of the classes when you decide.

Comment: Also, you should stick to C# naming conventions - all class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: If what you want to achieve is to group some related classes into one "bucket" then use namespaces.

Comment: True Java does not allow that. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its OK, and you don't need to do that if you don't want to.
C# allows many classes in any file, and allows nesting over any number of classes, so both ways are OK.

Comment: Oh perfect I didn't know that. Thanks for advice